# send up down arrow keys to process through pipe in linux using c language

Tags: c, linux, bash

I have created two processes using fork. Created a pipe. Parent will write keys at write end of pipe and child stdin(0) will be duplicated by read end of pipe. Up to know its working very well and good for alphabets. 
But i want to send up and down arrow keys also, please help me.

```
int main()
{
   int fd[2];
   char enter = 10;
   char *exit = "exit";
   char up = 193;//what i have to use here
   char down = 194;//what i have to use here
   pipe(p);
   if(fork())
   {
    write(p[1],&up,1);              //not working
    write(p[1],&down,1);            //not working
    write(p[1],exit,strlen(exit));  //working 
    write(p[1],&enter,1);           //working
    wait(NULL);
   }
   else
   {
    close(0);
    dup(p[0]);
    execl("/bin/sh","sh",NULL);
   }
}
```

Please help me,

Comment: is `char` type `unsigned` on your platform?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". What is the expected behavior and what actually happens?

Comment: Are you sure the ASCII code of up and down are 193,194 ?

Comment: IIRC codes for arrow keys are escaped. Something like `\x033[A`

Comment: Because there is no explication what is not working and the question is tagged `bash` I am just guessing. Maybe you wanted to invoke `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`?

Comment: not working means actually for up it has to move cursor to up and for down cursor not going down.

Comment: I am not sure ASCII codes i just tried ..

Comment: `UP` & `DOWN` are not single characters. They are a series of characters, **which depend on your terminal**. For many (not all) terminals, `UP` is `<ESC>[A` & `DOWN` is `<ESC>[B`.

Comment: i just tried /bin/bash same behavior.

Comment: If we send like UP is <ESC>[A & DOWN is <ESC>[B then child will reading it as string. So how to solve this ?

Comment: @subrahmanyeswaraswamymurala don't send "<ESC>", send the character code for escape - decimal 27 IIRC, octal 33. You can include it in a C string eg "\033]A".

Answer (score 3):

There are several points:

1.) You have to invoke a shell which supports terminal editing with arrows. On a usual Linux this may be `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`.

2.) `bash` is checking whether it's input is coming from a terminal device or not. Depending on this, it behaves like an `interactive shell` or not. It seems that you want to use it in interactive mode. However pipe is not a terminal device. To get it into interactive mode you can use bash option "-i" on its invocation.

3.) As pointed by commentaries, on a usual Linux X-terminal codes for arrow up and down are multi character strings like "\033[A" and "\033[B". It depends on the device and environment you are using, maybe your values are correct for your system.

The following code works on a usual Linux environment:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   int p[2];
   char enter = 10;
   char *exit = "exit";
   char *up = "\033[A";
   char *down = "\033[B";
   pipe(p);
   if(fork())
   {
    write(p[1],up,3);
    write(p[1],down,3);
    write(p[1],exit,strlen(exit));
    write(p[1],&enter,1);
    wait(NULL);
   }
   else
   {
    close(0);
    dup(p[0]);
    execl("/bin/bash","bash","-i",NULL);
   }
}
```

Also, you shall test return values of `pipe` and `fork`. Personally I'd write it like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   int p[2];
   int r;
   char command[] = "\033[A\033[Bexit\n";

   r = pipe(p);
   if (r < 0) {
       perror("Can't create pipe");
       return(-1);
   }
   r = fork();
   if (r < 0) {
       perror("Can't fork");
       return(-1);
   } else if (r > 0) {
       close(p[0]);
       write(p[1], command, sizeof(command)-1);
       close(p[1]);
       wait(NULL);
   } else {
       close(p[1]);
       dup2(p[0], 0);
       close(p[0]);
       execl("/bin/bash","bash","-i",NULL);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried above code up and down not working and one more issue is, after exit from above code bash not responding to any input. I think we are redirected stdin of bash so it needs to close terminal and reopen.

Comment: What kind of computer and what OS are you using? To be pedantic, the code should close pipe fds however this shall be done automatically on exit.

Comment: intel i5-4570 CPU, with Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Hmm. Here it works fine. Remaining frozen means that it does not recognize `exit` command. To avoid freezing closing pipe descriptors may help. I am adding this to my answer.

Comment: hi Marian, is up and down keys working in your system..?